# Apple Magic Keyboard V1 not discoverable in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a late 2012 Mac Mini with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. Everything works great except the Magic Keyboard is not discoverable in the Bluetooth settings.

I have tested other Bluetooth devices and they are discoverable.

The Magic Keyboard is discoverable on my Windows 10 machines as well as my iPhones.

Any ideas what the problem might be or how to fix?